# HDTV only detected when turned off (connected via DisplayPort to HDMI)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I tried to connect my LG HDTV (42" LD650) to my MacBook Pro 13" (mid-2010) using a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter. When I plug the cable in, my MacBook's screen flickers every time but the TV is only detected when it is in standby mode. Its status will switch to "No Display Connected" the moment I turn it on.

Here is what System Profiler shows when the TV is in standby mode:

```
NVIDIA GeForce 320M:

  Chipset Model: NVIDIA GeForce 320M
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCI
  VRAM (Total): 256 MB
  Vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID: 0x08a0
  Revision ID: 0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3533
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Resolution: 1280 x 800
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Built-In: Yes
LG TV:
  Resolution: 1920 x 1080 @ 50 Hz
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Television: Yes
```

I tried the TV and HDMI cable using a Windows PC and it worked instantly.

Is my TV somehow incompatible with the MacBook Pro, or is my adapter faulty, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just bought a new adapter (same type/manufacture) and updated to EFI 2.0 - the problem is fixed, now.

Answer (score 2):

While the TV is on standby, try going into System Preferences > Displays Preferences and set your displays to mirror.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately enabling the mirror option didn't work. The TV is still disappearing from the Displays Preferences when it's turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a graphics card switching app like gfxCardStatus?  I had a similar problem when I first started connecting to my tv because I was set to use Intel graphics only.  The Intel graphics chipset doesn't support HDMI output.

I see in your system profiler output the NVidia card, but I'm wondering if you're still somehow switched to the Intel...

Comment: No, I'm using the 13" MacBook Pro without Intel graphics.